# string kernels for GP/SVM regression

Tags: shogun

I want to solve a small regression problem where the inputs are variable-length strings from a small vocabulary. I'd like to use Gaussian Process regression with some kind of string kernel. (SVM regression also ok.)

I see from [this page](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/api/latest/dir_6a663499555dd5464c25e1814dcac07e.html) that shogun supports many kinds of string kernels - can someone please provide a high level summary (with references to papers) of how they work?

I'd also like to see a worked example (in python), since I've never used shogun before. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675240/string-subsequence-kernel-and-svm-using-python) on stackoverflow, but it's dated from 2014, and it's not clear if the interface is up to date.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: i'm just about to finish the string kernels tutorial jupyter notebook, i'll paste here the link how you can use string kernel in shogun.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation pages of string kernel classes contain the information you are looking for. For example:

- http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/api/latest/classshogun_1_1CPolyMatchStringKernel.html contains a high-level summary.
- http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/api/latest/classshogun_1_1CSalzbergWordStringKernel.html refers to the paper.

Quite likely not all classes will contain either one piece of information or the other.